# Use variable while rust's iter.filter closure parameter has a mutable borrow to it

Tags: rust

In rust, when letting rust's `iter.filter` closure parameter capture a local variable, and I mutate that local variable in that closure, I am unable to use it at all until i finish using the iterator. It is obvious in my Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
fn main() {
    let my_str = "12345";

    let mut num_i_need = 1;

    let iterator = my_str
        .chars()
        .filter(|code_char| {
            // ... logic to see if `code_char` should be filtered..
            num_i_need += 1;
            true
        })
        .peekable();

    dbg!(num_i_need); // <- problem

    // Now when we loop:
    for my_char in iterator {
        dbg!(num_i_need); // <- problem
        dbg!(&num_i_need); // <- problem
    }

    dbg!(num_i_need); // <- fine
}
```

I hope to be able to use the variable `num_i_need` outside of `.filter`'s closure (I don't intend to mutate it outside the closure) and without needing to use a `Cell`

I had to use a `Cell` to get the example to work:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let my_str = "12345";

    let num_i_need = Cell::new(1);

    let iterator = my_str
        .chars()
        .filter(|code_char| {
            // ... logic to see if `code_char` should be filtered..
            num_i_need.set(num_i_need.get() + 1);
            true
        })
        .peekable();

    dbg!(&num_i_need); // fine here

    // Now when we loop:
    for my_char in iterator {
        dbg!(&num_i_need); // <- NO problem, is fine
    }

    dbg!(num_i_need); // also fine
}
```

However in my actual codebase, I have 3 variables rather than 1 here, so I find this to be kind of undesirable and I am wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to achieve this without a `Cell`

Comment: In the example you gave: no. But in your real code, perhaps.

Comment: I am confused as to how it would be different in my real code. The iterator is the same and the kind of variables I'm using (numbers) is the same..

Comment: For `Copy` types I'd use `get` instead of `take` and you probably want `set` instead of `replace` to make it a little more clear but otherwise no.

Comment: Because maybe in your real code, you can consume the iterator differently or something.

Comment: I use the iterator in my real code only slightly differently: I am running a `while let Some(x) = iter.next()` loop and using the iterator again inside of that loop in a `while let Some(x) = iter.peek()` loop So probably no difference with that. I will probably stick to using Cell. Edit: That reminded me of the reason of why I didn't want to just put the `filter` logic inside the beginning of my for loop, it was because I am using `iter.next` and `iter.peek()` in multiple places other than that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting my `.fillter` to a `.scan` so that it can hold state, and it just passes that state on each `.next()` on the iterator, to keep filtering I used a `.filter` after my `.scan` (although that is not shown in the simple example here)

```
fn main() {
    let my_str = "12345";

    let iterator = my_str
        .chars()
        .scan(1, |num_i_need, code_char| {
            *num_i_need += 1;
            Some((num_i_need.clone(), code_char))
        }) // you would have a `.filter` here to filter stuff out instead
        .peekable();

    // Now when we loop:
    for (num_i_need, code_char) in iterator {
        dbg!(num_i_need); // <- NO problem, is fine (Without Cell!!)
        dbg!(code_char); // (also fine)
    }
}
```